# Vertical 3D Bar using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need this vertically:

[image: Picture: Need this vertically]

I tried a few things, but, I'm messing up something with the bottom layer and colors inside it.

EDIT:

1. I want colors to be started from the bottom of the bar, going upwards.
2. How do I add the bottom layer of the bar? I'm messing up with its height.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}

.progress-wrapper {
  width: 60px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.progressbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg);
}

.side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
}

/* .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
} */

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-60px);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.bar {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 5px rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.3);
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="progress-wrapper">
        <div class="progressbar">
          <div class="side front"><div class="bar"></div></div>
          <div class="side back"><div class="bar"></div></div>
          <div class="side bottom"><div class="bar"></div></div>
          <div class="side left"><div class="bar"></div></div>
          <div class="side right"><div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the result of what I tried:

[image: Picture: Result of what I tried]

What am I doing wrong? Am I going the right way? Is there any other less messy way to do this? (NOTE: I don't want to use HTML Canvas.)

Comment: you didn't include a .bar on inside the right div

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, added. What I want is:
I want colors to be started from the bottom of bar going upwards.
How do I add the bottom layer of the bar? I'm messing up with it's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the answer to my second question about colors.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsH61.png)

According to the height of the color fill in the bar, adjust its position in the bar by using the translateY() method.
Example: By adding `height: 200px; transform: translateY(100px)` ( where the height of the container is 300px ) in ".bar" class in CSS solves the problem.

Still, I couldn't figure out about the bottom layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the height of `.bar`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}

.progress-wrapper {
  width: 60px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.progressbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg);
}

.side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
}


/* .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
} */

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-60px);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.bar {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 5px rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.3);
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="progress-wrapper">
    <div class="progressbar">
      <div class="side front">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side back">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side bottom">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side left">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side right">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it not vertical for you?

Comment: Yes, it's not vertical for me

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Wait, sorry. something was wrong with my computer. it's vertical now!